Как в данном коде формируется высота блока?
Встретил в проекте изображение со следующими стилями:
<img class="image" src="image.jpg">

.image{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1920px;
    height: calc((100vh - 656px) / 2 + 330px);
    min-height: 330px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

Не могу понять, как формируется значение height и min-height.
Причем после сборки данная формула заменяется на такую:
.image{
    height: calc(50vh + 2px);
    min-height: 330px;
}

Определил, что 656px - это минимальная высота блока .wrapper (обертка всего контента). Он может быть или выше, или 656px, не меньше.
Откуда берутся значения height и min-height?

Ну min-height очевидно же прописано прям в стилях как есть

А с height самая банальная школьная арифметика: раскрываем скобки, деля оба слагаемых на два 100vh/2 - 656px/2 + 330px → 50vh - 328px + 330px — дальше просто складываем пиксели и всё 50vh + 2px

Там загвоздка в том, что значение в min-height совпадает со значением в формуле. То есть несколько блоков, например - calc((100vh - 656px) / 2 + 410px) и min-height: 410px

Ну совпадает, ну и что?
